# nodejs : My /public/index.html file does not appear on the screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, public

```
|project-name
|  client
|    public
|      index.html
|  server.js
```

↑ Project structure

My purpose is to display index.html(in public) in server.js.

[ server.js ]

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')

app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('listening on 8080')
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/public')))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/public/index.html'))
})

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/public/index.html'))
})
```

I wrote the code as above, but when I run node server.js to open the server and connect to localhost:8080, nothing happens.

[image: localhost:8080 screen]

It seems that the path is not wrong, but I wonder why the React project I made doesn't come out.

[ public > index.html ]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/public/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/public/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="/manifest" href="/public/manifest.json" />
    <title>Project Name</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[ index.js in client ]

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; // 추가됨
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

[ App.js in client ]

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Main from './pages/Main'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Register from './pages/Register'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Main />} />
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
          <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Let me know if you need more code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the best way to render public HTML files.

Set the view engine like that.

```
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index');
    });
```

The second option is no need to set the view engine.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/about.html');
});
```

Comment: Keep it up and help folks on SO

Comment: I tried changing the code to set view engine and use res.render() , but the result is the same... But thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use npm command to start server

```
npm start
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).